# Source Control at home

Tags: .net, version-control

I am trying to setup a dev environment at home. My primary development environment is VS.NET 2008 (now it is VS 2010 Premium) with SQL Server 2008.

Objectives / Requirements : 
- Should be simple and lightweight
- Should have a Visual Studio plugin (cost should be less than $50, if its not free)
- should work just fine with continuous integration systems like TFS and CruiseControl.NET
- VSS is not an option.

Thanks in advance,

SK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) offers a free, easy to install SVN server for Windows. They have a VisualSVN plugin that integrates with Visual Studio (but is not free - [$49](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/purchase/) for a personal license).

[AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is an open source alternative to the commercial VisualSVN plugin for Visual Studio integration but I've never used it before so I can't comment on it.

Answer (score 3):

What about just using TFS?

Or you could use subversion with ankhsvn for vs integration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Perforce's free 2-user license, and I'm pretty happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend mercurial or git as distributed version control systems seem to be the latest trend

Answer (score 1):

Subversion and switch to TeamCity for continuous integration

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing alone, [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com) is free for up to two people and five machines, and works very well for a single-developer model.

If you don't mind your projects being opensource, [Github](http://github.com) implements Git servers, or for $5 a month, you can have 5 projects closed-source.  That's a very different development model than perforce/cvs/subversion/vss-- take a look at [hginit](http://hginit.com) for a tutorial on distributed version control before going this route, it will really help.